# JQuery fancybox rounded corners problem in IE

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Fancybox rounded corners are coming in all browsers except IE with the following code.

```
 jQuery('#fancybox-inner').css({'-moz-border-radius':'10px', '-webkit-border-radius':'10px', 'border-radius':'10px'});
           jQuery('#fancybox-outer').css({'-moz-border-radius':'10px', '-webkit-border-radius':'10px', 'border-radius':'10px'});
     jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').css({'-moz-border-radius':'10px', '-webkit-border-radius':'10px', 'border-radius':'10px'});
```

How can i get rounded corners for fancybox in IE.

Here is the my code:

http://phone.invox.com/widgetconfig/mcwidget8/test.html

Please find "call us" button on left and when you click on it ,it will load fancy box.

Thanks
Yasin

Answer (score 1):

IE 7, 8 [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) border-radius property.
Try [this](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser).

Answer (score 1):

As Lex mention IE does not support border-radius property, for IE you need to do the rounded corners using images (The image of each rounded corner) and position them on the corners you want

http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with this:

```
   $("a.fancy").fancybox({
  'titlePosition' :  'inside',
  'overlayShow' : true,
  'overlayOpacity': 0.5,
  'overlayColor' : '#000',
  'onComplete' : function() {
   DD_roundies.addRule('#fancybox-title', '5px', true);
   DD_roundies.addRule('#fancybox-outer', '10px', true);
  }
 });
```

where I'm using http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend You to use the CSS3 PIE JS plugin: http://css3pie.com/

You simply implement the plugin on your site by adding this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In fancybox CSS find: #fancybox-content and #fancybox-outer
Add CSS3 border-radius params to those ID's.

And in ie.js place something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fancybox-outer, #fancybox-content').each(function() {
        PIE.attach(this);
    });
});
```

Voila, you have now rounded corners in IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this to work with fancyBox v2. My approach was based on user1167656's approach (thanks!):

Add the CSS3 PIE plugin js version of the plugin to your site for IE < 9:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html/script/PIE.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In the fancy box attach js code catch the afterShow callback and add this code:

```
$.fancybox({

    <other fancyBox options here>

    'afterShow': function(){
        if (window.PIE) {
            $('.fancybox-skin').each(function() {
                PIE.attach(this);
            });
        }
    },

    <other fancyBox options here>

});
```

This works for me in IE8.

Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

In your head section. It may be solve you problem.